# Xcode Swift play youtube video on Native video player?

Tags: ios, video

i am looking for pod on `swift` to play `Youtube` video on ios native player just like [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) unfortunately [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) is only for objective-C i can't find any swift pod work like this , all i found they embed iframe video and the youtube logo will appear which will allow user to click on it and miss up the page when the full page open .

how i can play youtube video on `ios` native `video` player ? without html embed !

**Exactly like :** 
[image]

Comment: Just a sidenote. this violates YouTube policy and will get your app rejected too. This is the only way you are allowed to show videos: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper . And your question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: @ user5890979 my app is more than 1 year on the store and its still not yet rejected or suspended

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although XCDYouTubeKit is written in Objective-C, it integrates fine with Swift. Here is some sample code to use it with Swift 3:

```
struct YouTubeVideoQuality {
    static let hd720 = NSNumber(value: XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.HD720.rawValue)
    static let medium360 = NSNumber(value: XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.medium360.rawValue)
    static let small240 = NSNumber(value: XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.small240.rawValue)
}

func playVideo(videoIdentifier: String?) {
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier(videoIdentifier) { [weak playerViewController] (video: XCDYouTubeVideo?, error: Error?) in
        if let streamURLs = video?.streamURLs, let streamURL = (streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQualityHTTPLiveStreaming] ?? streamURLs[YouTubeVideoQuality.hd720] ?? streamURLs[YouTubeVideoQuality.medium360] ?? streamURLs[YouTubeVideoQuality.small240]) {
            playerViewController?.player = AVPlayer(url: streamURL)
        } else {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , you just make my day :)

Comment: @0xced Not playing all videos from youtube url giving error XCDYouTubeVideoErrorDomain -2.